# How can I stop my basement from filling with water?

Tags: basement

I have my house in a sloped area ,it has  problems of water seeping inside the basement area which gets filled up to 1 to 2 feet height what may be the solution for this .... i have tried all water proofing things,need to get a solution.

Comment: The standard answer is that you need to stop the water from reaching your basement walls.  Once it gets to the walls, it will eventually find a way in.  Or, let the water in, and dig trenches along the interior walls to a sump pump to pump the water back out.

Comment: If you've already tried all the solutions, then I think the next option is to move.

Comment: Lower the water table. Sealing the inside is just an exercise in creating blisters and always fails.

Answer (score 2):

In many ways this is an easier problem to solve on a sloped area than a flat one.

First - waterproofing products applied to the inside of the basement are almost never an effective solution. The pressure of exterior water eventually pops them off the inside wall. On the outside they can work.

So, the solution is in two general forms - one is directing surface water away from the house (this involves making sure that the ground on the upslope side (actually, on all sides, including the upslope side) of the house slopes AWAY from the house for at least 10 feet/3 meters) so that water running on the surface of the ground is carried away from and around the house, not into it.

The other is to provide a drain to carry water away from the basement and out to a lower portion of the slope below basement level. The BEST (but most involved, generally) place to put such a drain is around the outside of the basement, below basement floor level. That involves digging up all around the house to place the drain (and anyone building a new house should remember that "when the foundation is being placed, this will only cost you the price of the pipe, since the hole is dug anyway.") Obviously a large project, also obviously the most effective solution. Water cannot get into the basement if it's carried away by a pipe before it can build up against the basement walls. You can also add a waterproofing membrane to the outside of the walls if you go this route, since the walls will be exposed, and you can additionally add a "drainage sheet" outside the waterproofing membrane to help get water down to the drain pipe. In most cases simply having the drain pipe and backfilling with stone or gravel should be adequate, since the stone or gravel provides the drainage path to the pipe, and the pipe means theres no way for water to build up against the side of the foundation.

If you cannot manage to dig a drain all the way around the house, you should at least run one from the low side, below basement floor level, out to a lower point on the slope where it can drain by gravity. You can knock a hole in the basement floor and install a sump for this to connect to, or not, depending on the water flow pattern in the basement. While there are plenty of people (such as the ones on a flat site who have little choice in the matter) who simply put in a sump and a sump pump, and pump the water out, if you have a slope available I'd strongly suggest the use of a naturally-sloped drain pipe to remove the water by gravity, without power or anything mechanical involved.

Answer (score 0):

If the water is already in your basement to a level of 1-2 feet you can install a sump pump without the piping around the outside of your foundation (called drain tile). This would be done by simply cutting the hole in the floor and putting the piping in and the pump in. I would say that with that much water you want to check for other sources of water. (sewer backups and foundation cracks come to mind) When you put the pump without drain tile the pumps area of effect is much smaller. This means that the areas closest to the pit will be driest. With the amount of water you're dealing with this may not be enough. 2' is a lot of water to move even in a normal circumstance. If your not wanting to dig around the outside of your foundation you can also dig around the inside. This would involve cutting about 2' from the edge and breaking out that concrete. Then you would put your drain tile in and lead it to the pit and pump it out. I deal with this a lot at work and seriously the best thing you can do is install one or two pumps. If you put two in put them at different corners. Optimally diagonal but both in say the back or the front would be okay too. I grabbed a picture from [here](http://tomlinson-cannon.com/services/basement-waterproofing/).[image: Drain Tile Installed] No relation I just liked the way the picture explained what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Hmmm. I have a small sump which is essentially unneeded unless we get massive flooding (50-year/100-year levels), and which has no drain channel as a result. I periodically think about putting in a channel so that if we do ever need it the water goes around the perimeter rather than across the floor, but I'm honestly not convinced that would be an improvement in my case.

Comment: I'd add a discharge line check valve in the diagram above (depending on where the lien terminates). The pump can be rendered virtually ineffective without one (i.e. the discharged water, or excess surface water can come down through the line).

Comment: The pumps I've seen have a check valve at their output. Are you suggesting a second one?

Comment: Yes usually there is one a couple of feet above the slab.